# API to get URL to currently active live stream

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to embed a Vimeo livestream in a static website that is behind corporate authentication. For that we upgraded our Vimeo account to be able to use live streaming and the domain-level privacy setting.

Now, I don't see any API to get the currently active live stream, only `https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?fields=files` which I could then filter for the `hls` type and get the playlist link to then feed the ID from it into a form of `https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url={video_url}` to get the embed content.

Is there an easier way to do this? Will it even work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be possible using a recurring event https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002114347-Recurring-events

Answer (score 0):

No, the Vimeo API doesn't currently support interactions with Vimeo Live or Live events. The API can generally only interact with completed and archived Live events.